# Does pytest fixture only do patching in main thread?

Tags: multithreading, mocking, pytest, fixtures

I have a conftest.py containing all relevant mocks I needed (Redis DB connection, SQLAlchemy, Flask, etc)
When I tried to test with more than a single thread (main thread) I could see that other threads were not familiar with all mocks I did.
Any help on how I can run -an inside test- with several instances and "save" the mock context?

Comment: This should work if you’re using threads and not processes. You should create these threads during the test session, e.g. as threaded fixtures.

Comment: But then you say “multiple instances” so it sounds like you might be using multiple processes or sessions to set ups your tests? If so, how could they know to be mocked? We’ll need code to help.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado well, yeah. I want several threads, not a processes.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have the fixtures in the test function context: 
test_multiple_access(tmp_dir, data_base): 

If I'm running it without threads, it looks good. When I'm adding threads they are not familiar with data_base and tmp_dir, so the test is fail on this kinda things